# Align the text with the bullet to the top of the row

Tags: vertical-alignment, bullets

I want to align the bullet item text to the top of the cell. How can i do that? This is the tex syntax :

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
        \hline
        \toprule[0.05em]
        Category & Methods & Advantages & Disadvantanges \\ 
        \hline
 
        Conventional HE
        & Gonzalez
        & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
            \item Improve the contrast.
            \item Simple and no parameter tuning required.
        \end{itemize}
         
        & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
            \item Unable to adjust the degree of enhancement.
            \item Often produce unwanted visual artifacts.
            \item Produce unnatural image appearance, such as the mean brightness of image is 
                  different between the original image and enhanced image. 
        
        \end{itemize} \\
     \addlinespace
        
        Local-based HE
        & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] 
          \item AHE 
          \item CLAHE 
          \item CEDHE 
        \end{itemize}
    
        & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
            \item Can preserve the details
          \end{itemize}
        
        & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
            \item Increase computational time and complexity
            \item Might caused overenhancement and blocking effect  
        \end{itemize}   \\
        \addlinespace
                
 \hline
 
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

The result from the above code is as below figure :
[image]

I want to align the text with the bullet to the top of the cell.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try using `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`.

Comment: Thank You Bernard. I have tried but nothing change

Answer (score 1):

Since you're making use of the `enumitem` package, I'd like to suggest that you employ that package's `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke itemize-like environment that is automatically (a) embedded in a `minipage` environment (to remove the whitespace at the top and bottom) and (b) sets the options `nosep` and `left=0pt` (in order order to promote compactness of the lists).

Oh, and don't use `\hline` (or `\cline`) and instead exclusively use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,enumitem,booktabs,ragged2e}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1} % create a bespoke itemize-like env.
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,nosep,left=0pt,
            before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
            after ={\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.14\textwidth}
                        p{0.16\textwidth}
                        p{0.3\textwidth}
                        p{0.3\textwidth} @{}}
        %%%%%\hline
        \toprule %[0.05em]
        
        Category & Methods & Advantages & Disadvantanges \\ 
        %%%%%\hline
        \midrule
 
        Conventional HE
        & Gonzalez
        & \begin{myitemize}
            \item Improve the contrast.
            \item Simple and no parameter tuning required.
        \end{myitemize}       
        & \begin{myitemize}
            \item Unable to adjust the degree of enhancement.
            \item Often produce unwanted visual artifacts.
            \item Produce unnatural image appearance, such as the  
                  mean brightness of image is different between 
                  the original image and enhanced image.       
        \end{myitemize} \\
        
        \addlinespace
        
        Local-based HE
        & \begin{myitemize} 
          \item AHE 
          \item CLAHE 
          \item CEDHE 
        \end{myitemize} 
        & \begin{myitemize}
            \item Can preserve the details
          \end{myitemize}   
        & \begin{myitemize}
            \item Increase computational time and complexity
            \item Might caused overenhancement and blocking effect  
        \end{myitemize} \\  
                     
        %%%%%\hline
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico. very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I propose this simplified code, using the `\compress`command, which makes latex believe the start of a cell is the start of a minipage  and thus suppresses all spacings above a list.

I also removed the horizontal spacing before bullets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \makeatletter
        \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt, nosep}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.1\textwidth}>{\compress}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\compress}p{0.3\textwidth}> {\compress}p{0.3\textwidth}}
        \hline
        \toprule[0.05em]
        Category & Methods & Advantages & Disadvantanges \\
        \midrule
        Conventional HE
        & Gonzalez
        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Improve the contrast.
            \item Simple and no parameter tuning required.
        \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Unable to adjust the degree of enhancement.
            \item Often produce unwanted visual artifacts.
            \item Produce unnatural image appearance, such as the mean brightness of image is
                  different between the original image and enhanced image.
        \end{itemize} \\
     \addlinespace

        Local-based HE
        & \begin{itemize}
          \item AHE
          \item CLAHE
          \item CEDHE
        \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can preserve the details
          \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Increase computational time and complexity
            \item Might caused overenhancement and blocking effect
        \end{itemize} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the lists in the cells of the columns of type `p` don't start with a vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt, nosep}
    \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
        \hline
        \toprule[0.05em]
        Category & Methods & Advantages & Disadvantanges \\
        \midrule
        Conventional HE
        & Gonzalez
        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Improve the contrast.
            \item Simple and no parameter tuning required.
        \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Unable to adjust the degree of enhancement.
            \item Often produce unwanted visual artifacts.
            \item Produce unnatural image appearance, such as the mean brightness of image is
                  different between the original image and enhanced image.
        \end{itemize} \\
     \addlinespace

        Local-based HE
        & \begin{itemize}
          \item AHE
          \item CLAHE
          \item CEDHE
        \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Can preserve the details
          \end{itemize}

        & \begin{itemize}
            \item Increase computational time and complexity
            \item Might caused overenhancement and blocking effect
        \end{itemize} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]